# Prolog binary tree node value count

Tags: prolog

Can anyone help me how to realize predicate in Prolog which counts the all the node numbers of a binary tree?

For example:

```
tree1(tree(1,
        tree(2,
            tree(3,nil,nil),
            tree(4,nil,nil)),
        tree(5,
            tree(6,nil,nil),
            tree(7,nil,nil))
    )
).
```

Would return 28. Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you sure about 23? Looks like 28 to me, or I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: My mistake, it was 28

Answer (score 1):

The trivial recursive solution. *Not* tail-recursive.

```
treesum(nil, 0).
treesum(tree(X,T1,T2), S) :-
    treesum(T1, S1), treesum(T2, S2),
    S is X+S1+S2.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, helped me a lot. And how about multiplication? How could I realize that?

Comment: in this case I can't just change '+' to '*', because I did that and Prolog all the time gave me answer 0(The program GNU Prolog). Because when I traced this multiplication example, in each node it multiplyed also 0. Here is an example of multiplication, just first part, bu all the others are the same:

 
      6    4  Exit: 0 is 3*(0*0) ?  `

Comment: @John You are joking, right? Here is a riddle: When you add 0, nothing changes. What do you have to multiply to so that nothing changes?